# KnockoutJS "with" binding before model is available

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 SPA web application using KnockoutJS, which is a bit awkward because, as I understand it, when the page initially loads in an SPA there is generally no data until an AJAX call retrieves it. When I try to bind all sorts of data inside a block with an attribute like `data-bind="with: myData"`, the whole DOM inside that node is emptied out until myData becomes valid, which makes me nervous if certain script might be relying on having those elements available to attach script to or something. It also looks bad to have chunks of the page disappearing and reappearing during the load process. So I've devised a variation of the `with` binding that will prevent descendant bindings if the value is empty, which currently looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.safeWith = {
    'init': ko.bindingHandlers.with.init,
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if ((value != undefined) && (value != null))
            ko.bindingHandlers.with.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```

Then I simply use `safeWith` instead of `with` to make sure my DOM doesn't go away while waiting for `myData` to be populated.

My questions are:

1. Is this a common problem with SPAs using knockout, and if so, how is it normally dealt with?
2. Is my way of dealing with this safe or do I risk duplicate events/bindings being applied somehow or some risk I'm not aware of?
3. I'm surprised in my roaming about the web learning about knockout and related technologies I haven't run across this. Are there good reasons to *prefer* having sections of the DOM to go away when the object to which they're bound is empty; am I making a mistake by trying to keep it around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a custom `bindIf` binding handler that improved our results significantly by postponing binding logic until the observable has a valid value inside it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindIf = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        return { 'controlsDescendantBindings': true };
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        if (!$(element).data("bindIfPassed") && valueAccessor()) {
            $(element).data("bindIfPassed", true);
            ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
        }
    }
}
```

Applied to a high level node like this:

```
<div data-bind="bindIf: myObservable()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see reasons why you would not want the DOM inside a with-bound element to disappear, but they are very few. Pretty much all of them involve DOM manipulation that requires certain timing. For example, setting the focus to the first input field when a view is shown. Sometimes, the workaround for such problems isn't pretty, in which case a binding like yours would definetly help a lot.

In general,

1. I suppose this is somewhat of a common problem. You mention a few
   problems: Scripts relying on the presence of those elements: in
   general, I would respond that your scripts are wrong. Now that's a
   bit harsh, but I do feel it's a bit of a code smell that your
   scripts would come crashing down if a certain DOM element isn't
   available. Second, you feel that parts of the dom disappearing and
   reappearing is not such a good thing. In this case, maybe you should
   'reset' the observable in your with binding to something else than
   'null'. Create a 'blank' instance of whatever object normally goes
   into the observable, and use that instead of null, so your DOM
   remains intact. If this is not an option, then your scenario is not
   really a use case for the with-binding (and your own binding would
   indeed be a helpful one for such scenarios).
2. I'm not entirely sure. I tried to look into the with-binding, but for some reason I can't spot it in the Knockout code. It's tested easily though, just set up an event binding within the with binding, then change the observable's value a few times. It does seem a bit worrying that you never update the with-binding when the value is undefined/null though: I can imagine this can easily lead to binding errors further down the DOM.
3. There are certainly good reasons for this, especially in a Single Page Application. I'm doing a pretty huge application with Knockout as an SPA. By proper use of the with-binding and cleaning up my viewmodels when a view is unloaded, I can manage memory (of which DOM nodes are a big part) pretty easily, even though views are cached on the frontend. The application would run extremely slowly if we didn't have a mechanism for unloading DOM nodes when the relevant data is not present. This is a data-driven approach I really enjoy: the parts of the DOM that are shown are the parts that are relevant, because the data is there.

Comment: If you search the knockout JS file for `'with'` (including the quotes) you will see that it is created with a call to `makeWithIfBinding`. `'with'` only occurs once in my version of knockout.js (`knockout-2.2.0.debug.js`). I understand wanting to remove parts of the DOM that don't apply, but don't you also have to deal with parts of the DOM for which the model is not yet loaded, but it will be loaded when the page is done loading? Do you encounter this problem in those cases?

Comment: I do encounter it occassionally, but I generally avoid showing the view before it has finished loading the data. Do you work with a single page app or is it multi-page?

Comment: I am prototyping an application in which I expect that each main function will be a mini SPA. Loading new records within the page will use AJAX calls to retrieve new data and not re-load the whole page, but navigating to another function will load a whole new page.